# Java, Using javaFX for the main menu then switching over to JFrame for the game itself

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jframe

I am here to ask if it is possible to use JavaFX for the main menu of my game and then switch over to JFrame for the game itself.

The reason I want to do this is because I know how to make pretty fancy game menus in JavaFX and not in JFrame and JavaFX to me also looks alot more fancy then JFrame..

I will truly appreciate any help you give me.

Comment: Yes, just create and show the `JFrame` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`

Comment: So why don't you just use JavaFX for everything?  Swing is obsolete.

Comment: @James_D
Do i create the javaFX and Jframe in the same class?

Comment: Entirely up to you, just make sure you create any JavaFX `Stage`s on the FX Application Thread and the `JFrame` on the AWT event dispatch thread.

Comment: @James_D i'll give that a shot now.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem
I'm actually using this for a small gameEngine i am creating and i have already three quarters the way finishing this engine idk if i can switch now without redoing everything.

Comment: OK, but I think you're looking for trouble.  Do you really want both the FX Application Thread and the AWT Event Thread running side by side?  In theory, each part of the application should receive the appropriate events.  In practice, you may end up with all sorts of bugs where you're expecting an event to show up in one part of the application, and it turns up in the other.  Your application will end up being quite difficult to maintain, and probably prone to bugs.  I strongly recommend you use just one platform or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done: you just need to make sure you use the correct threads for everything. In particular, ensure you launch the Swing application on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.

Here is a simple example.

SwingApp:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SwingApp extends JFrame {

    public SwingApp() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("This is the Swing App", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        quitButton.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        add(quitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and then

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LaunchSwingFromFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        Button launch = new Button("Launch");
        launch.setOnAction(e -> {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingApp::new);
            primaryStage.hide();
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane(launch);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot James_D and everyone who commented

Comment: Accepted your answer